# What are some reasons migrating a site to Cloudflare could cause an increase in the number of active connections to a load balancer?

Tags: amazon-ec2, connection, cloudflare

I use an application load balancer (AWS EC2 instance) to manage traffic to my site. I recently changed CDNs to Cloudflare. With my previous CDN, I observed an average of about 80 active connections per hour to the load balancer. After switching to Cloudflare, I now observe an average of 800-1200 active connections per hour.

The load balancer is using keep-alive connections with an idle timeout of 60 seconds. The difference in PoPs between Cloudflare and the legacy CDN is too small to account for such a large difference in connection count. I'm not sure what else I might be missing. Any pointers as to the source of this connection increase would be much appreciated. Thanks!